# JSON Post to Spring controller not working

Tags: java, ajax, json, spring, spring-mvc

JSON Post to Spring controller not working....  I get into the controller but then I am getting some crazy errors.

Javascript:

```
function doAjaxPost() {  

    alert("doAjaxPost Called");

     var queryString = $('#htmlform').serialize();

       $.ajax({
            contentType : "application/json",
            dataType : 'json',
            type : "POST",
            url : contexPath + "/service/employee",
            data : queryString, //json serialization (like array.serializeArray() etc)

            success : function(data) {
                alert("Thanks for submitting.  \n\n" + response.result);
               // response
            },
            error : function(request, status, error) {
                   alert('Error: ' + e); 
            }
        });
    }  
</script>
```

java/Spring/Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(headers ={"application/json;charset=UTF-8"}, method=RequestMethod.POST, value="/employee" )
    public ModelAndView updateEmployee(@RequestBody Employee employee ) {
        System.out.println("in put body:");
        System.out.println("HELLO WORD" + employee.toString());

        return new ModelAndView(XML_VIEW_NAME, "object", employee);
    }
```

Now for the error:

```
2012-06-13 13:00:01,809 [http-8080-2] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - DispatcherServlet with name 'rest' processing POST request for [/RESTful/service/employee]
2012-06-13 13:00:01,813 [http-8080-2] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapping [/employee] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [dw.spring3.rest.controller.EmployeeController@c58f769] and 1 interceptor
2012-06-13 13:00:01,844 [http-8080-2] DEBUG org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker - Reading [java.lang.String] as "application/json;charset=UTF-8" using [org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter@221a5770]
2012-06-13 13:00:01,846 [http-8080-2] DEBUG org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker - Invoking request handler method: public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView dw.spring3.rest.controller.EmployeeController.addEmployee(java.lang.String)
in post
2012-06-13 13:00:01,870 [http-8080-2] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [dw.spring3.rest.controller.EmployeeController@c58f769]: org.springframework.oxm.UnmarshallingFailureException: JAXB unmarshalling exception; nested exception is javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Premature end of file.]
2012-06-13 13:00:01,873 [http-8080-2] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [dw.spring3.rest.controller.EmployeeController@c58f769]: org.springframework.oxm.UnmarshallingFailureException: JAXB unmarshalling exception; nested exception is javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Premature end of file.]
2012-06-13 13:00:01,873 [http-8080-2] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [dw.spring3.rest.controller.EmployeeController@c58f769]: org.springframework.oxm.UnmarshallingFailureException: JAXB unmarshalling exception; nested exception is javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Premature end of file.]
2012-06-13 13:00:01,874 [http-8080-2] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Could not complete request
org.springframework.oxm.UnmarshallingFailureException: JAXB unmarshalling exception; nested exception is javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Premature end of file.]
    at org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller.convertJaxbException(Jaxb2Marshaller.java:761)
    at org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller.unmarshal(Jaxb2Marshaller.java:682)
    at org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller.unmarshal(Jaxb2Marshaller.java:665)
    at dw.spring3.rest.controller.EmployeeController.addEmployee(EmployeeController.java:61)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:436)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:424)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Premature end of file.]
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.createUnmarshalException(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:335)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.createUnmarshalException(UnmarshallerImpl.java:481)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:199)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:168)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:157)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:125)
    at org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller.unmarshal(Jaxb2Marshaller.java:678)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Premature end of file.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:198)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:177)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:391)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(XMLScanner.java:1391)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1034)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:625)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:116)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:488)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:819)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:748)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:123)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1208)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:525)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:195)
    ... 31 more
Jun 13, 2012 1:00:01 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet rest threw exception
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Premature end of file.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:198)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:177)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:391)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(XMLScanner.java:1391)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1034)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:625)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:116)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:488)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:819)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:748)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:123)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1208)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:525)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:195)
```

Comment: The error is for `addEmployee`, but you have pasted `updateEmployee`. Can you fix the question please? And also maybe add line numbers to your controller so we can cross reference with the stack trace.

Comment: Are you getting your `Employee` model filled by POST request. Yes, it would be better if you correct your stacktrace. It's not showing your SOP statements that you have written.

Answer (score 0):

**Convert the query string to json string**

```
var postData = {};
jQuery.map($('#htmlform').serializeArray(), function(n, i){
postData[n['name']] = n['value'];
});
```

**Pass json string instead of queryString in ajax post**

```
$.ajax({
            data : JSON.stringify(postData), //convert json object to string
            success : function(data) {                   
            },
            error : function(request, status, error) {
            }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, it works for me on Java servlet doPost().
    $(document).ready(function(){

> ```
>   $("button").click(function(){
>       var mydata = {"name":"abc","age":"25"};
>       $.ajax({
>           type: "POST",
>           url: "http://localhost:8080/...",
>           data: JSON.stringify(mydata),
>           contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
>           dataType: "json",
>           success:function(data){
>             if(data.status === "success"){
>               alert("Success");
>             } else if (data.status === "error"){
>               alert("Fail");
>             }
>           },
>           error:function(thrownError){
>             console.log(thrownError);
>           }
>         }); 
>   });
> ```
>
> });